# Convert string in to Multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, google-docs, app-inventor

I have a string like

```
var str = ["\"1\",\"Aaram\",\"11\",\"9\",\"18\",\"2900\",\"26100.00\",\"33750.00\"","\"2\",\"Araijnan Kayiru\",\"22\",\"18\",\"20\",\"3100\",\"55800.00\",\"75000.00\"","\"3\",\"Araijnan Kodi\",\"33\",\"27\",\"22\",\"3300\",\"89100.00\",\"123750.00\""]
```

I need JavaScript to make it Multidimensional array to pass to a Table.

This is required to pass the above string generated from app inventor list array to google doc Table using Google apps scripts.

**Updates:**
As suggested by  Mister Jojo, the code works and table is created in Google Doc. However, if I get the same data from doGet(e) function, only normal string is inserted instead of Table.

```js
function ManageSheet(TABLE1HERE){
  var docTemplateId = "my google doc template here";
  var someName = "SomeNameFile";
  var copiedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplateId).makeCopy(someName);
  var docOpen = DriveApp.getFilesByName('SomeNameFile').next().getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docOpen);
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var rgel=body.findText('TABLE1HERE');
  var element=rgel.getElement();
  var childIndex=body.getChildIndex(element.getParent());

    var strArr = [ "\"1\",\"Aaram\",\"11\",\"9\",\"18\",\"2900\",\"26100.00\",\"33750.00\""
  , "\"2\",\"Araijnan Kayiru\",\"22\",\"18\",\"20\",\"3100\",\"55800.00\",\"75000.00\""
  , "\"3\",\"Araijnan Kodi\",\"33\",\"27\",\"22\",\"3300\",\"89100.00\",\"123750.00\""
  ];


    var result = strArr.map(row=> JSON.parse(`[${row}]`) );

  body.replaceText('{branch_name}',"Some Thing");
  body.replaceText('{borrower_name}',"Some more Thing");
  body.getChild(childIndex).asText().setText('');
  body.insertTable(childIndex,result);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");

}
```

However, following code does not work, when the table data is taken from doGet(e) function.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return ManageSheet(e);
}
function doPost(e) {
  return ManageSheet(e);
}

function ManageSheet(e, TABLE1HERE){

  var docTemplateId = "my google doc template here";
  var someName = "SomeNameFile";
  var copiedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplateId).makeCopy(someName);
  var docOpen = DriveApp.getFilesByName('SomeNameFile').next().getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docOpen);
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var rgel=body.findText('TABLE1HERE');
  var element=rgel.getElement();
  var childIndex=body.getChildIndex(element.getParent());

    var strArr = [ e.parameter.table1here ];
    var result = strArr.map(row=> JSON.parse(`[${row}]`) );

  body.replaceText('{branch_name}',"Some Thing");
  body.replaceText('{borrower_name}',"Some more Thing");
  body.getChild(childIndex).asText().setText('');
  body.insertTable(childIndex,result);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");

}
```

Output will be same as doGet data posted from URL. No table will be insterted, plain text will be appended as paragraph.

Comment: Well is that string actually escaped correctly? The way it is written is a syntax error.

Comment: What are those `""`? Please [edit]

Comment: Two double inverted commas "". That's how the string is generated from app inventor app. There are three arrays in that string each seperated by a space.

Comment: There are three rows having 8 columns each. When I call the list of data, the above string is generated. I can make necessary modification before passing as single parameter to google script. Futher, through apps script, I want to make the string into multidimensional array.

Comment: We don't know what your data are in reality . What you show doesn't exist in javascript syntax. Use JSON.stringify( DATA,0,2) on your system and show us the result instead of this wrong one

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. I got following when using one tile called JsonObjectEncode.              ["\"1\",\"Aaram\",\"11\",\"9\",\"18\",\"2900\",\"26100.00\",\"33750.00\"","\"2\",\"Araijnan Kayiru\",\"22\",\"18\",\"20\",\"3100\",\"55800.00\",\"75000.00\"","\"3\",\"Araijnan Kodi\",\"33\",\"27\",\"22\",\"3300\",\"89100.00\",\"123750.00\""]

Answer (score 0):

this way :

```js
let strArr = 
  [ "\"1\",\"Aaram\",\"11\",\"9\",\"18\",\"2900\",\"26100.00\",\"33750.00\""
  , "\"2\",\"Araijnan Kayiru\",\"22\",\"18\",\"20\",\"3100\",\"55800.00\",\"75000.00\""
  , "\"3\",\"Araijnan Kodi\",\"33\",\"27\",\"22\",\"3300\",\"89100.00\",\"123750.00\""
  ]

let result = strArr.map(row=> JSON.parse(`[${row}]`) )
 
console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: It throws the error          TypeError: strArr.map is not a function

Comment: what is the type of your `strArr` ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a list of lists in App Inventor. Simply set this list to a string in App Inventor, then you will have a stringified json list. You will, of course, need your Screen1.properties to have the "ShowlistsAsJson" ticked.

[image]